# List of incompatibilities between Webkit, Gecko and IE browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser, web-standards

OK, I have a couple of similar questions here.

Browsers I'm talking about:  *IE - Gecko (Firefox) - Webkit (Google Chrome, Safari)*

**QUESTION 1**

Of the three specified browsers, which kind follows CSS3 standards the closest?  Which is the worst at following CSS3 standards (when referring to the latest standards).

**QUESTION 2**

I'm trying to create a site that directly shows (gives examples of) differences between the supported things in the three specified browsers.  Is there a list of things not supported natively by any of the three browsers that should be (i.e. defined in CSS3 standard)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best place to find answers to your questions is [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/).

This site has compatibility tables for all the major browsers (and versions), for over a hundred different browser features.

The list of features it covers is pretty comprehensive. It also points out the status of the feature in question - ie whether it is an approved standard or whether it's still a work-in-progress with the standards committees.

Most of the official CSS3 and HTML5 standards are in all of the major browsers, but there are many features which are in various stages of approval but which have been added to one or more browsers anyway. (indeed, IE9 is some way behind the other browsers, but when Microsoft released it, they were at pains to point out that it supported all the currently approved standards; they didn't implement anything still pending approval, but that left them already some distance behind the others even when they launched, as the others aren't playing by that rule).

This means that the answers to your questions are likely to be in a constant state of flux, as new features are thought up, others are implemented in various browsers, and others work their way through the standards committees.

Comment: Also, if you need runtime feature detection of HTML5 and CSS3, have a look at Modernizr: http://www.modernizr.com/